# .TXT FILES IN MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file-io

I would like to know about loading .txt files in matlab. The vector data i have is given as a  row for which i would like to calculate mean and other stats..

Kindly suggest me a way for that..

Thanks,
Aishwarya

Comment: The format of your data is a little unclear. If you add an example showing the data format like those given in the answers by Amro and Ngu we should be able to give you a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *txt* file with row vector data that look like:

#### file.txt

```
3.4
-4.1
1.5
-3
...
```

Then you can simply use:

```
data = load('file.txt');   #% load file
N = length(data);          #% number of elements
mu = mean(data);           #% mean
sigma = std(data);         #% standard deviation
plot(data)                 #% simple plot
```

Answer (score 0):

[csvread](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/csvread.html)

Given the file csvlist.dat that contains the comma-separated values

```
 02, 04, 06, 08, 10, 12
   03, 06, 09, 12, 15, 18
   05, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30
   07, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42
   11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66
```

To read the entire file, use

```
csvread('csvlist.dat')

ans =

     2     4     6     8    10    12
     3     6     9    12    15    18
     5    10    15    20    25    30
     7    14    21    28    35    42
    11    22    33    44    55    66
```

Or you can use [importdata](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/importdata.html).