# How to load .txt file on Matlab and how to work on it?

Tags: matlab, file-io

I'm new on Matlab. I don't know how to load .txt file end then open it to start work. The file is composed by 1 column with over 10.000 elements. I'm going to open it and then to deleted some elements, these deleted elements must be more little than a fixed value, how can I do it.
Thank you very much for your time.
Mario

Comment: Please post some example data and what results you expect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892357/txt-files-in-matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the following part of the user guide: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/import_export/br5s7ig.html

or use the MATLAB editor if you want to do it interactively:

```
edit(textfilename)
```